# See what has been installed via MacPorts

Tags: macports

Is there a way to see all I have installed via MacPorts?

I know I have installed Apache and php 5.3.8, but I'd like to see what else I have installed.

Comment: Woo-hoo! 100! :-)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use  `port installed` to list all of your ports.

Comment: You can do `port installed requested` to [see only the packages that aren't dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050617/list-of-installed-macports-without-dependencies)

Comment: `port installed requested` does exactly what I wanted: show packages that I chose to install.

Comment: `port installed requested` list all installed ports that were explicitly asked for, include all versions. To only list currently active installed ports that were explicitly asked for, use `port installed requested and active` instead.