# List of installed MacPorts without dependencies

Tags: macos, macports

When I do `port installed`, I get useless list of hundreds of items. However, only a handful of these are ports I actually installed first-hand. The rest are dependencies that I have no need to relate directly to.

Is there a way to list only the ports I actually installed, ie. those I typed in on the command line manually? Like a top level node list or installation history file or something?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

MacPorts has the concept of requested and unrequested ports.

Try `port installed requested`.

See `man 1 port` for more information on 'requestedness' and pseudo-targets.

Comment: To filter out inactive versions of installed ports, use `port installed requested and active` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of *literally* all installed ports that nothing depends on, you can run

```
for port in $(port echo installed | awk '{print $1}'); do [ -z "$(port echo installed and depends:$port)" ] && echo $port; done
```

(warning: this will take a while).