# See what has been installed via Homebrew

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

(I asked a [similar question regarding MacPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191737/see-what-has-been-installed-via-macports) some time ago)

Is there a way I can see what all I have installed via Homebrew?  *I'm currently running OS X 10.8 but I don't think that matters...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see what has been installed simply enter

```
brew list
```

---

If you need more help you can type `man brew` and `brew` in the command-line interface. This will tell you more about the commands and options.